# "Oracle initialization or shut down in progress" problem

Tags: database, oracle, oracle9i

I installed oracle 9i before 20 days, it was working fine till now but now when i try to login from scott user with correct password it is giving oracle initialization or shut down in progress error and not letting me login.

Any solution please?

Comment: What is the platform and how do you connect (locally from the dbserver of via the network)?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the alert.log file, and then the last entries in that file.

My guess would be that it has been generating archive log files and has filled up the location where they go.